# systemd-resolved's ResolveUnicastSingleLabel setting does not seem to work with non-search domains

Tags: systemd, dns, systemd-resolved

`ResolveUnicastSingleLabel=yes` still does not seem to solve the problem of non-fully-qualified domain names (NFQDN) not being resolved.

I use a single wireguard tunnel to my corporate network (with domain **example.net**) whose dns server at **10.28.0.1** can resolve the NFQDN **test** into an IP address **10.28.0.20**.

1. With non-search domain we get no results:

```bsh
resolvectl dns wg0 10.28.0.1
resolvectl domain wg0 ~example.net
resolvectl query test
```

> test: resolve call failed: 'test' not  found

2. Setting it to a search-domain simply qualifies the NFQDN into a FQDN by appending .example.net, which relies on the server doing DNS forwarding of test.example.net to **10.28.0.20**. That's not what we want:

```bsh
resolvectl domain wg0 example.net
resolvectl query test
```

> test: 10.28.0.20                             -- link: wg0
> (test.example.net)
>
> -- Information acquired via protocol DNS in 15.7ms.
> -- Data is authenticated: no

3. When I specifically tell `resolvectl` to not search (but still use the search domain), we get the desired result:

```bsh
resolvectl query --search=no test
```

> test: 10.28.0.20                             -- link: wg0
>
> -- Information acquired via protocol DNS in 15.2ms.
> -- Data is authenticated: no

4. Annoyingly, because **example.net** is now a search domain, `ping` and other services also seem to redirect to the company's main reverse proxy when I am trying to connect to non-existing domains:

```bsh
resolvectl query cyclo.brussels
```

> cyclo.brussels: resolve call failed: 'cyclo.brussels' not found

```bsh
ping cyclo.brussels
```

> PING cyclo.brussels.example.net (10.28.20.3) 56(84) bytes of data

Am I still doing something wrong or is `ResolveUnicastSingleLabel=yes` simply not working with a non-search domain?